# Error 142 from filepicker.io JS API v2 convert call after pick call with cropping UI

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

I'm using a paid Filepicker.io account.

I'm getting back error 142 from a convert call via the JS API version 2.

The error object's `toString` method tells me to to include `filepicker_debug.js` for more information, but that file gives a 404, so that's not helpful.

[The docs](https://www.filepicker.com/documentation/file_ingestion/javascript_api/convert?v=v2) say that 142 means "The user's file cannot be converted with the requested parameters." The parameters I'm sending are `{width: 240, height: 240}`.

My code runs a `pick` operation (which makes use of the cropping UI), then passes the "`Blob`" which is available in the callback to a `store` command (which works) and a `convert` command (which does not).

I tried removing the `store` command, so just `pick` and then `convert`, but there is no change.

The `convert` options I'm passing as said above are `{width: 240, height: 240}`. I tried also passing extra options like `fit:clip` or `fit:scale` or `rotate:exif` but this doesn't change anything. I also tried to do this after a `pickAndStore` call rather than just a `pick`; also no change.

I'm not editing the "`Blob`" which comes back from the `pick` command, and it works with the `store` command, so I don't think that could be the issue (as it was in [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489769/error-code-142-when-converting-image-solved)). I don't think I'm doing anything wrong there.

If I look at the HTTP response which comes back from Filepicker, it's a 400 code and tells me, for example, `[uuid=16CB6B72517940C7] Invalid conversion parameters`. If I look at what was actually sent, I think I may see the issue.

This particular POST request was sent to `https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/ndayWb5GTmNyPoAOjSdg/convert?crop=955,621,954,954/convert&_cacheBust=1436084602394&plugin=js_lib`, with the posted form data `width: 240, height: 240, storeLocation: "S3", storePath: "storyimg/local/iq84xYTsu1jJaRcq_small.jpg"`.

That GET parameter `crop=955,621,954,954/convert` looks rather suspect. I see in the "`Blob`" the property `url: "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/ndayWb5GTmNyPoAOjSdg/convert?crop=955,621,954,954"`. It looks to me like some JS in the library isn't expecting the crop parameters (presumably added by the cropping UI) to exist here, and is blindly adding on `/convert` and the rest.

Filepicker people: please fix this.

I tried to work around it for by editing the "`Blob`" object before passing it to `convert`. The workaround looks a little like this:

```
filepicker.pick({
    cropRatio: 1,
    services: ['convert', pickerType],
}, function (blob) {
    filepicker.convert($.extend({}, blob, {
        url: blob.url.replace(/\/convert\b.*/, ''),
    }), {
        width: 240,
        height: 240,
        crop: blob.url.replace(/.*[?&]crop=([0-9,]+)(?:&|$).*/, '$1').split(','),
    }, storeOptions, function (blob) {
        console.log("Convert completed successfully", blob);
    }, handleError);
}, handleError);
```

This is ugly, and after testing, I see that it doesn't actually even work. The crop does not take place. If I remove the `width` and `height` it crops properly, so I know the way I extract the crop parameters is correct, but with `width` and `height` the entire image is resized, rather than just the cropped portion.

On the subject, the [REST API documentation for convert](https://www.filepicker.com/documentation/file_processing/image_conversion/image) says

> **Crop and Resize:** we strongly recommend against combining a resize (specifying width or height) with the crop functionality, as it has indeterminant effects depending on whether the crop is applied before or after the image is resized.

I begin to question why I am using this service at all.

It seems that unless Filepicker fixes these issues, I am forced not to allow the user to crop the image, or to do the `convert` only after my `store` operation (which has already cropped the image) completes. This means I can't parallelize saving the full size and thumbnail images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did a deployment today that fixes this issue where people would receive an error when first they cropped an image using our cropper tool, and then tried to take that url and pass it into the convert method. Now if you pass a url into the convert method that is already directed at the convert endpoint, the crop parameters will be parsed and the resulting image will be both cropped and converted in whatever way was specified.

We have also added a crop_first parameter which can be set to true. If this parameter is set to true, then the crop will occur before any other conversion happens (resize, rotate, etc).

Comment: The same code I was originally running is now working as expected. Thanks for fixing this.